# Tensorflow per_process_gpu_memory_fraction not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm using Tensorflow-gpu 1.10 because I had problems with cuDNN. I wanted to limit how much gpu it's using to 40% so I did

```
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.4
session = tf.Session(config=config)
```

I looked at Omen Control Center to see how much of the GPU I'm using, and it was using like 70% of the GPU instead. I'm not getting any error messages. My GPU is a GTX 1080. I have looked all over online and other people had similar problems, but none of the solutions worked. I'm also using Keras for for the models and layers. I am also doing this in Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Do you find cause or find different method? I am having same issue at Windows OS.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.4)
session = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing alternative function. Have you tried in Windows OS?